# Finding correct memory IC

Tags: memory, protocol

I have a project where I need to store data (~16Mo) on a memory IC and be able to fetch the data fast (<36000bits/s) (with DMA in the idea).

My µcontroller is an Arduino DUE. So far I've tried a flash (SD card) with SPI but I can't make it use DMA and it's not as fast as I want (~10 times slower).

When I use SPI, I suppose it does not uses the DMA because the delay between two packet is long and seems like µcontroller taking care of the data transfer itself rather than the DMA doing it.

However I²S (wich is easier to program, and run at any speed fixed by the clock) works with the DMA by default and packet are send immediately one after the other.

I've looked for memory IC I can use with I²S but it doesn't seems to exist. I've looked FIFOs but they don't work in serial and parallel-to-serial converter are not a thing apparently.

It's weird I didn't find someone trying what I'm trying or some project identicial unless I'm too far ahead of my time but I doubt it.

There are surely things I didn't understand correctly or solutions I don't know ; if you have clarifications, tips or anything to help I would be glad to read you.

Thanks

Comment: So since spi on the sam3x8e that the Arduino due is based on does work via DMA, the fact that you can't make it use DMA is a software problem that you'd need to solve with any other interface just as well. So, I'd recommend trying to solve that problem - the other interfaces that microcontroller has aren't any better suited for this job. Would also be good if you could put numbers to your definition of "fast"! What would be, in hard numbers, not "as good as possible" be fast enough for what you're planning to build?

Comment: Just to be clear, the sam3x8e has a dedicated "16-bit external bus interface supports SRAM, PSRAM, NOR and NAND Flash" but I doubt it's available through the Arduino Pinout, though I haven't checked. If you used that, your external memory would become part of the regular address space of your Microchip.

Comment: Some better ARM MCUs support HyperBus external memory which is capable of very high speeds using DMA. I don't think the  SAM3X8E does.

Comment: You should probably indicate approximately how much memory, it's characteristics (nonvolatile, RAM etc.), and what you mean by "fast" in **quantitative** terms.

Comment: The MCU has native SD card bus support. The problem may be that using SD card over SPI is slow. Perhaps the limitation is that you are using what Arduino provides you and your requirements have grown out of what Arduino can provide to you. Also if you need less than or more than 36 kilobits per second, even SPI should provide faster without DMA.

Comment: "I've looked for memory IC I can use with I²S but it doesn't seems to exist." – Do you mean I²C? I²S is usually for audio.

Comment: I mean I²S. I know it's for audio, it's more than 10 times faster, easy to work with, I use it to send data to a DAC. I was hoping I could use it to fetch data the same way I send it. I'm wondering if I²S is just a protocol or a protocol and an interface.

Comment: *36000 bits/s* That's "nothing" - even memories decades ago could do that. Can you please say what rate you actually need?

Comment: @Vlad I2S is an interface specification/protocol that's completely exclusively used for audio. Also, it's **not** faster than SPI, I really don't know where you get that from – certainly not from the datasheet, which tells it like it is: the SPI bus can run at any rate that's a factor of the main clock rate, including the same. So, think, beyond 80 Mb/s! (not that you'll build stable communications that way, but unlike I2S, it's not a bus solely for audio data and hence has no restriction to slow audio data rates).

Comment: @Vlad I'm voting to close this question as missing information if you don't state what speed you actually need, and what you've done to verify that SPI with DMA doesn't work – it **really** should.

Comment: What is speed if not bits/s (genuine question, not sarcasm) ? I'm aware 36000bits/s is not fast nowadays but the project doesn't need to be faster (and couldn't probably but that's not revelant)

Answer (score 2):

Infineon [16Mb EXCELON series](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-CY15B116QN-40BKXIE-DataSheet-v03_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7d0d8da4017d0eea4dc6734b&utm_source=n403&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=202208_glob_en_atv_ATV.P.RAMMemory&utm_content=e1_) is available, operates with an SPI interface at up to 40MHz and is non-volatile (FRAM technology). You should be able to use DMA with the SPI interface. I2S is  designed for sending stereo audio (hence the L/R clock).

[image]

A bit pricey though, and available only in 6mm X 8mm BGA package, however those were not constraints in the question. Only 8 of the 24 balls are connected.

Comment: FRAM was my first thought. +1

Answer (score -2):

You can use DMA (Direct Memory Access) only with the internal main bus of the microcontroller. The idea is like [this](https://open4tech.com/direct-memory-access-dma-in-embedded-systems/):

[image]

As you can see, the DMA controller needs access to the bus. This bus is not available externally on Arduino DUE. This means you will go through the selected peripheral to access any external memory like SPI, I2C, etc., and it's never "Direct" access.

Some microcontrollers provide the internal bus interface on their pins (like a 32-bit bus). Those microcontrollers can support external memory that is treated exactly like the internal memory. With that bus, you can have an external memory with DMA.

However, memories with parallel buses could be faster than serial peripherals (like I2C and SPI). But, it is not DMA. Have a look at this discussion:

https://forum.arduino.cc/t/parallel-library-for-due-external-memory-bus-static-memory-controller/149085/6?page=2

Comment: If the DMA is used with SPI peripheral then the SPI to memory uses DMA.

Comment: Can you explain more? Do you mean the SPI itself or the SPI memory? If you mean the SPI memory can use the DMA, do you have a reference that I can read about this?

Comment: How about just reading the data sheet or reference manual of the MCU if you want to know how DMA works with SPI on that MCU.

Comment: The datasheet talks about the DMA for SPI communication. Not DMA access for external "SPI memory"! I think what you mean is the DMA for SPI itself, not the SPI memory.

Comment: Then I think the problem is wording. If you can use SPI with DMA, then it can be said that everything accessed over SPI can be done using DMA. You simply are claiming that using SPI memory with DMA is impossible, and by extension, nothing external to the MCU can use DMA.